# how to write function that makes pow operation with base of type float?

Tags: pow

I don't understand why this code doesn't work..
help?
thanks ♥

```
    float powOperation(float base, int n)
{
    if (n == 0)
        return 1;
    return base *powOperation(base, n - 1);

}
```

Comment: What programming language is it?

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? Does it not compile? is the answer wrong?